# Is the feeling of blood pulses a symptom of low blood pressure?

Tags: sleep, blood-pressure, sleep-deprivation

When I go to sleep after a long waking time or when I am about to wake up after not sufficient sleep (or less than 8 hours of sleep) , I feel the blood flow in the back of my head in the form of strong pulses. Is this a symptom of low blood pressure, or what might be the cause for this behavior?

Comment: In my experience, when I feel what you describe, my pulse is usually low and so is my blood pressure.